# How to sort array by number elements and ignore string elements

Tags: typescript

How can I sort an array in ascending order by the elements which are numbers while putting the elements that are strings at the back of the array?

I have tried this but I don't think it's correct(all ql ids that are strings as "NOT_SET", I want to have them at the back of the array (in typescript):

```
 const qaInspectionLinesSorted = _.forEach(qaInspectionLinesGroupedByType, (item => {
        return item.sort((ql1, ql2) => {
          if (ql1.id.toString() !== "NOT_SET") {
            return 0; 
          }
          if (ql1.id.toValue() > ql2.id.toValue()) {
            return 1;
          } else if (ql1.id.toValue() < ql2.id.toValue()) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;

        });
      }));
```

An item has this structure if it helps:

```
 _id: UniqueEntityID { value: 9 },
 props: {
   qaInspectionTypeId: [QAInspectionTypeId],
   qaInspectionLineStatusId: [QAInspectionStatusId],
   qaInspectionLineNotes: 'HIIIIII',
   qaInspectionId: 1
 }
```

Comment: Do you care about the resulting order of the strings, or does it not matter and you just want all the strings to be at the end of the array in any order?

Comment: I do not care about the order of strings, can be in any order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparator is returning 0 when `ql1.id.toString() !== "NOT_SET"` is true, regardless of anything about `ql2`, which is definitely wrong, because you haven't done a comparison between two elements from the array.

Here's my solution:

```
function sortStringsLast<T>(arr: T[], key: (x: T) => string | number): T[] {
    return arr.sort((x, y) => {
        const xKey = key(x), yKey = key(y);
        if(typeof xKey === 'string') {
            return typeof yKey === 'string' ? 0 : 1;
        } else {
            return typeof yKey === 'string' ? -1 : xKey - yKey;
        }
    });
}
```

I am not sure from your code exactly how you are deriving a sorting key that is either a string or a number, so I wrote a function accepting a `key` parameter to derive the sorting keys however you want for your own data. Note that when `xKey` is a string, you only want to return `0` when `yKey` is also a string; otherwise we return `1` to indicate that `x` should appear after `y` in sorted order, because `xKey` is a string and `yKey` is a number.

If you did want the strings to be in some specific order, you could easily replace the `0` in the above function with some other comparator, e.g. `xKey.localeCompare(yKey)`.

Test:

```
const arr = [1, 'foo', 4, 'bar', 3, 'baz', 2];

// [1, 2, 3, 4, "foo", "bar", "baz"]
console.log(sortStringsLast(arr, x => x));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgJygZSmmYDmyAMgIbJQA8AKgHwAUJaaAXIlQNoC6ANIgNYBTAJ6s6AD1ZUAlIgC8NFDjz5EAH0RgQAWwBGAtFMldEAbwBQiS4jQCoINEkZoAdKgx1xvITPmmLVgIgEckQxAGlhOX5hcSkvCKEowSE6bwBufwDLGGA6KCEABwE4YFCEuVlZRAByclwCaplzLJbrW3skfKKSxCFyyqrapQbEAH5EAAZEVgBGDNbEAF9EAQAbZAE-BYCbOwdELuLSvsiBmrrlarHEAFoZ6bLIm96E+dbFzKWpDI+zILAQk4ouwZrxqsA4HBqrwACxgnSMaGIADM8JIAC8kQAmTgZMwAenxiBBvCxvFRiDhiAARBC4NTeNSEWgGTSEejqZw-sE4KsBM5VnB8HQ3FhhoRSOQGExeGI5AoxFJvmYgA)

Comment: looks good but I don't understand what do you need the key function for and why are you passing it as a parameter to the function?

Comment: @blanches From the code in your question, it looks like `ql1` and `ql2` are not of type `string | number`. For your use case `key` might be something like `x => { const str = x.id.toString(); return str !== 'NOT_SET' ? str : x.id.toValue(); }`.